# Azure DevOps Work items unassigned user not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I added a new user to my project and he's an admin too to it, but when I click on create a new user story/bug/... his name doesn't show up, I have to look him up manually:
[image]

I want to be able to see him once I click in that box. He is already in my users under project settings.

Comment: I also accidentally deleted my name from the list with the red cross so I had to type it every time. I had to log out and n in and then my name reappeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Work items unassigned user not found

That because drop down is actually **a cached list of users you have assigned tasks to** in the past.

So, you just need enter their first name or email address to search him and assign to him. Next time, you will see him in the drop down list.

Details steps:

- When assigning a user to a task, enter their first name and click the
  search button. The user should be brought back by the search. Assign
  the user to the task.
- Next time you go to assign a user to a task, if you click on the drop
  down list should now display the user as it is now cached.

Hope this helps.